# Не добавляется телефон в amocrm

Tags: php

Задача. Создать контакт и добавить к нему телефон. После создать сделку и присоединить к ней созданный контакт. Делаю всё по документации. Контакт успешно добавляется. Сделка тоже. Контакт добавляется к сделке. Но, в контакт не добавляется телефон.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я вывел список контактов, чтобы увидеть какой id у телефона.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И использую вот такую запись для добавления. Функция thePostData всего лишь берёт данные с формы. Если заменить любым строковым значением, всё-равно не добавляется.

Answer (score 0):

используйте enum = MOB или WORK для телефона